# Missing MissingVKeyWitnessesUTXOW when signing tx with PaymentSigningKeyShelley_ed25519 key

Tags: cardano-cli, signing-key-file

I'm trying to get skey `PaymentSigningKeyShelley_ed25519` from `PaymentExtendedSigningKeyShelley_ed25519_bip32`.
Here is the extended key:

```
{
    "type": "PaymentExtendedSigningKeyShelley_ed25519_bip32",
    "description": "Payment Signing Key",
    "cborHex": "5880608550a89ba16a920b365e77131ba1c702d5d825025d1c91190992a6465df7545919c017426267e5a9eff84ecb35f3cdbb6701036141ade1cc3980c6166e741b1dbaa54ec25531278af95388ff2f96b5c986b33fc693ebfc3c17e050cbe57a7f62777711a09bd4b66522668489fbe3b7f61a0f89c8331b30399bc69bff604976"
}
```

and normal key:

```
{
      "type": "PaymentSigningKeyShelley_ed25519",
      "description": "Payment Signing Key",
      "cborHex": "5820608550a89ba16a920b365e77131ba1c702d5d825025d1c91190992a6465df754"
}
```

For address: `addr_test1qr69yj887txwu7ca7s9g5lr6sm7p8sf4dac295g7c44rfvma6t5aw0lpzxyk4r0r9tpdmremh0g37nal3q8fhjy97xwqpu4d5c` I can sign tx successfully using the extended key, but not using the normal key.

Here is the `cardano-cli (v1.35.3)` command I'm using:

```
cardano-cli transaction sign --tx-body-file tx.raw --signing-key-file payment.skey --testnet-magic 1 --out-file tx.signed
```

Does anyone knows what's wrong here?

Note: Using `Bip32PrivateKey#to_raw_key()` the result hex is 64 bytes instead of 32 from the origin key I shared. I was able to submit the tx using csl and 64 bytes from the extended key:

```
   static getPrivateKey(key: string): PrivateKey {
        if (key.startsWith('xprv1')) {
            return Bip32PrivateKey.from_bech32(key).to_raw_key();
        } else {
            const unhex = Buffer.from(key, 'hex');
            const decode = cbor.decode(unhex);
            try {
                return PrivateKey.from_normal_bytes(decode);
            } catch (err) {
                return PrivateKey.from_extended_bytes(decode);
            }
        }
    }
```

cborHex: `'5840608550a89ba16a920b365e77131ba1c702d5d825025d1c91190992a6465df7545919c017426267e5a9eff84ecb35f3cdbb6701036141ade1cc3980c6166e741b'`

cardano-cli isn't working with this 64 bytes version though.